# Representar de forma gráfica un ArrayList en Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy empezando en el mundillo de la programación en Eclipse y me gustaría saber como representar un ArrayList (de Doubles para ser más exactos) de forma gráfica (de la forma más sencilla posible), llevo un buen rato buscando por internet y no lo tengo nada claro,

En otros programas como Matlab es muy sencillo, ya que hay que solo hay que llamar a plot o stem,no sé si en Eclipse será lo mismo, pero aquí estoy muy perdido, si alguien me pudiese dejar un código de ejemplo se lo agradecería un montón, no tiene que ser muy elaborado con que se vean las lineas de las gráficas y los valores de los ejes (eje Y valor del Double y el eje X posición del vector) me vale me vale.
Un saludo

Comment: En Java no es tan sencillo como usar un plot en matlab, necesitarás utilizar alguna librería externa que pueda gestionar gráficos. Hacerlo a mano no es tan sencillo como poner un par de lineas de código...

Comment: Probaste alguna libreria para eso? Buscando en google aparecen fácil 3 gratuitas

Comment: Investigando por internet (sobre todo en inglés) he encontrado alguna cosilla que otra: XYSeries, ChartPanel, etc. Ya os comentaré resultados, más que nada porque seguro que me surge alguna duda XD. Sí @Klaimmore , he visto que hay que descargar alguna que otra librería... que cosa más pesada jaja si solo quiero dibujar un vector XD. Un saludo

Comment: Es que el api de java te proporciona un canvas para hacer puntos lineas y elipses, pero plotear? Nope